# Switching xib's in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, sdk, view, xib, switching

I'm having issues with switching xib's when I try to from my second view into the third.

I get into the second view from the first like this...

```
-(IBAction)startButtonClicked:(id)sender{

    Number2ViewController *screen = [[Number2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
    [screen release];

    }
```

But when I'm in the second view trying to get to the third view, the app crashes...

```
-(IBAction)nextButtonClicked:(id)sender{

    Number3ViewController *screen = [[Number3ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
    [screen release];

    }
```

I know how to go into one view and then immediately back using

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

How do you just keep going to different views though without having to go back first?

Comment: If you could post details about the crash that might help. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588853/the-community-driven-gdb-primer

Comment: as soon as nextButtonClicked is activated, the app crashes

Answer (score 4):

Based on what you've written, you're probably a lot better off using a [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this. It's specifically designed to be able to push new controllers in and manage notifications when these controllers change (like a new one is added or the current one is removed). `presentModalViewController:` is really designed for when you want to present a new view that takes over the entire application, performs a single function and goes away. Examples of this would be sending an email from within your app, viewing an external web page, taking a photo, presenting some about text, changing settings or other things like this. It's not really designed to manage a stack of view controllers that actually interact with each other.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `UINavigationController`